# Can I get more than 1000 records from a PrincipalSearcher?

Tags: c#, active-directory, multiple-users

I am trying to get all users from Active Directory using code:

```
PrincipalContext ad = new PrincipalContext(contextType, adserviceName, adContext, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, username, password);
UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(ad) {Name = "*"};
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher { QueryFilter = u };
foreach (var principal in search.FindAll()) 
{
    //do something 
}
```

But it returns only first 1000 rows. How I can retrieve All users and without using DirectorySearcher.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do that without using **DirectorySearcher**.

Code snippet -

```
// set the PageSize on the underlying DirectorySearcher to get all entries
((DirectorySearcher)search.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).PageSize = 1000;
```

Also see [If an OU contains 3000 users, how to use DirectorySearcher to find all of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722977/if-an-ou-contains-3000-users-how-to-use-directorysearcher-to-find-all-of-them)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the underlying `DirectorySearcher` and set the `PageSize` property on it:

```
using (PrincipalContext ad = new PrincipalContext(contextType, adserviceName, adContext, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, username, password))
{ 
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(ad) {Name = "*"};

    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher { QueryFilter = u };

    // get the underlying "DirectorySearcher"
    DirectorySearcher ds = search.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;

    if(ds != null)
    {
        // set the PageSize, enabling paged searches
       ds.PageSize = 500;
    }


    foreach (var principal in search.FindAll()) 
    {
        //do something 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
((DirectorySearcher)myPrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).SizeLimit = 20;
```